# Safari in-app browser opens in the background with delay

Tags: swift, swiftui

With iOS 16 we can now open a url like:

```
struct OpenURLExample: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com") {
                openURL(url)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Get Help", systemImage: "person.fill.questionmark")
        }
    }
}
```

That would open safari in an external browser (away from the app). How can it be open inside the app?

Until now I was using the following:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct Safari: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    // Wrapper to be able to open safari inside app
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Safari>) {
        return
    }
    
}

.fullScreenCover(item: $explorerUrl) { item in
    Safari(url: URL(string: item.url)!)
}
```

but with iOS 16 this looks inconsistent, it opens it after a couple of seconds (more than 5) and sometimes it opens a black screen first.

Is there a native way now in SwiftUI for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had kind of same issue in SwiftUI with iOS 16 and what I did is performed safari action on main queue. It takes the high priority by default and does the needful

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Launch safari with your specific URL here
}
```

I hope it will work for you.